# Firebase Database code not working after window.location is inserted in JS

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

This is the code of JS file makeroom.js-
The database part doesn't work after the window.location code is put. Any solutions?

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyD96Lgszg8M9TptKknYlfnCDsEfy9ZO2dQ",
    authDomain: "hwforfirebase.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://hwforfirebase.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "hwforfirebase",
    storageBucket: "hwforfirebase.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "297251167674",
    appId: "1:297251167674:web:ac070375a455971c7b1183",
    measurementId: "G-Z7PPXV5NEJ"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

document.getElementById("greeting_para").innerHTML = "Welcome," + " " + localStorage.getItem("NameForChatApp") + " " + "!";
function addRoom(){
      RoomName = document.getElementById("makeroom_input").value;
      localStorage.setItem("Room Name",RoomName);

      firebase.database().ref("/").child(RoomName).update({
            purpose: "Adding Room Name"
      });


      window.location = "chatscreen.html";



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing data to the database is an asynchronous operation, and it may take some time. Right now you're setting the `window.location` before the write is sent to the database. To ensure that write completes, you must wait with changing the location.

The simplest way to do that is by waiting until the `then()` of the `update` method gets called:

```
firebase.database().ref("/").child(RoomName).update({
    purpose: "Adding Room Name"
}).then(function() {
    window.location = "chatscreen.html";
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just saw it now, sorry. Will try and check.